# How can I give more weight/importance to certain values in my regression when my dependent variable is a ranking?

Tags: panel-data, ordinal-data

So I am currently studying the relationship between University Rankings (my dependent variable) and academic freedom (my independent variable, which can take values between 0 and 1).

I have a panel of hundreds of universities over 17 years.

At first, I was hesitating between a linear model (using OLS regression with fixed effects) and an ordinal model (since my dependant variable is a ranking going from 1 to 600). Some research showed me that an ordinal regression model might not be the best choice because of two reasons :

1. Non-linear regressions can be problematic when there is a lot of fixed effects
2. An ordinal regression model might not be optimal when there is a high number of different ordinal categories (my model has 105 categories : one for each number from 1 to 100, and then one for 200, 300, 400, 500 and 600).

So, knowing this, I have two questions regarding what I should do next.

Question 1 : is what I read in my research true ? Is it really not a good idea to use an ordinal regression model here ?

Question 2 : If I cannot use an ordinal regression, what could I do in order for my regression to take into account that losing or gaining ranks in the top 100 part of the ranking is way more impactful than at the bottom ?

What I mean by this, in the context of Univeristy Rankings, is that going from the 80th place to the 30th place should be considered way more of a big deal than going from the 500th place to the 450th.

Comment: One strategy is to add a variable to your data set:  in_top100 which would be zero if false and 1 if true.  Adding this as an additional predictor variable in your model may help.  And you may wish to include interactions with this new variable.

Comment: Thank you, that seems like a clever idea ! Though I am not that familiar with the notion of interactions. Do I just use this new variable as an interaction term on my other independant variables ?

Comment: Interactions can be included as products of the current independent variables in the model.  For example $y = b_0 + b_1 · x + b_2 · G + b_3 · (x·G)$ would be a model with a scalar variable $x$ and a (dichotomous) grouping variable $G$.  The equation if $G=0$ becomes $y=b_0 + b_1 · x$ and the equation with $G=1$ becomes $y = (b_0+b_2) + (b_1+b_3)·x$.  Inclusion of the interaction lets you see how the intercept AND slope change in the presence of the dichotomous variable.